# Using CoreLocation Framework to determine if user is in Texas

Tags: geolocation, gps, ios7, location, core-location

Ok, so I exploited to the state of Texas on the question header but what I'm trying to do is determine which state (in the United States) a person is located in as they are using my app.

I want to offer certain services from the app if the user is physically standing in a particular state.

Is there some sort of web service I can call with a set of long/lat coordinates and it will return the state information to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a dupe of [6778205](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778205/google-maps-geocoder-to-return-state) - use the Google geocoder service which can return address information. Somewhere in the address (see the discussion) can be found the state.

Comment: Thanks, ajwillia.  While I had seen Geocoder from google, I had been lead to believe that it had to be used in conjunction with a map and "push pins" for locations on a map...  I did not realize that there was actually an object built into the iOS dev kit called, CLGeocoder, along with examples.   I'm off and running.  Thanks again.